# Can't get some Facebook photos with large id

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, photo

The photo on https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10202647348127670&set=a.10202647345647608.1073741855.1316861248&type=1&theater, is public, but the api gives me:

> { error: { message: "Unsupported get request.", type:
>   "GraphMethodException", code: 100 } }

i'm using a token, and i found the image on my facebook home page.

I only want to get the direct link to the image.